# Hive metrastore Database in Postgresql External

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, hadoop, hive

We recently migrated hive metastore database from embedded postgresql(coming with cloudera hadoop) to external postgresql(standalone in vm server). After that we notified that there is increase of 5 to 10 seconds in query execution. May i know why it happens?. Postgresql config setting almost same except archive_mode which is on external postgresql, while in embedded postgresql it is off.

Comment: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions

Comment: Also: why are you using an outdated and [unsupported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) Postgres version?

Comment: "embedded" PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like an issue with the VM and/or network and not Postgres, if it is true that nothing else has changed, but only the "dedication" to another machine.

We had a bad VM configuration - my VM was on the same rack as our Scientists run their stuff. So each time they did anything - all resources went there.

Look at your VM, how much RAM and Processing power does it really have?
If you can afford it - give your your postgres more RAM and config it to cache most of the DB (or all). And if you can afford it - buy a dedicated server for Postgres. You'll have one for below $1k (with couple of SSDs and 32GB RAM).

For the rest: listen to a_horse_with_no_name, and give us additional info (and hell, if you use pg91 - upgrade to pg96, if you use anything below pg96 - upgrade!)

-- should be a comment, but my reputation is not enough for it.